# How to implement the notifyDatasetChange with Sugar ORM

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider, sugarorm

I have been wondering how your model define using sugar ORM can de notified of data set changed such as with android Content Providers.
I have a situation where i updated a model record in one activity and move to the previous activity, but the data is not reloaded when i move to the previous activity.
Don't know how the model can be aware that the data has change(updated) and automatically reload it self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually talking about is a SyncAdapter implementation on an ORM like SugarOrm which to my knowledge am not sure if sugar has such an implementation. You will have to do a custom implementation to achieve such a functionality. Here's a few approaches that may work for you.

1. You can should load your data/models in the onResume method of your activities/fragments. Here we may garantee that you have the latest snapshot of the data in the database and even when you come back from a different activity, it should already be updated.

   2. You can implement a static Broadcast receiver for your activities like so

public class MyModel extends SugarRecord implements Serializable{

```
int m_id;
String m_name;

public MyModel(){}

public void setter(...){...}
public Object getter(){...}
```

}

Activity 1 inside onCreate(...)

BroadcastReceiver dataBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver{

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    //retrieve the data model here from the intent or setdata for your adapter by loading all the data from the database
    MyModel model = intent.getSerializableExtra("MYDATA");
}
```

};

registerBroadCast(dataBroadcast, new IntentFilter("DATA_CHANGED"));

inside on Destroy()
unregisterReceiver(dataBroadcast);

Activity 2
inside your update/create model method for example

```
void createMyModel(){
    MyModel m = new MyModel();
    m.setMname("ice");
    long saveId = m.save();
    if(saveId > 0){
//fire the broadcast which activity 1 will receive and process accrodingly
        Intent mIntent = new Intent("DATA_CHANGED");
        mIntent.putSerializable("MYDATA", m);       
        sendBroadcast(mIntent)  
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the two propositions are reasonable. Depending on the functionalities of your activity you may use one of them. Good reasoning @larrytech